# Does position: sticky; work the same way for React components as well?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've read the following page "How to make a sticky sidebar with two lines of CSS"
https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-make-a-sticky-sidebar-with-two-lines-of-css-2ki7

and am trying to do the same for my React project, but the sidebar is not properly following when I scroll the page.

As far as I can tell, the only difference that I noticed between the example mentioned in the above article and my project is whether React components are used or not.

**[The article's example]**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    Main content
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sticky sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

**[My project]**

```
import React from 'react';
import Posts from './Posts';
import SearchAndRecommendation from './SearchAndRecommendation';
import Footer from './Footer';

class Home extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">
        <main>
          <Posts/>
        </main>
        <aside className="sidebar">
          <SearchAndRecommendation/>
          <Footer/>
        </aside>
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I used the same CSS code as the article in my project, but the `'position: sticky;'` is not working. Does using React component have anything to do with this?

By the way, I'm not planning to use `position: fixed;` as a solution. It worked to fix the header on the top, but when I tried it for the sidebar it was fixed on the top left corner. I want to fix the sidebar on the right side of the page.

Comment: Where is the CSS? Who renders `Home`, its not related to React, there are not differences.

Comment: do you also have the css applied to share ? A https://snack.expo.io/ or  https://codesandbox.io/s/ can also be usefull. But your relevant codes should be standing here